# In Postgis 1.5, how can I split lines in points while retaining the id?

Tags: postgis

## Hypothesis:

Having 2 linestring tables:

```
pipelines (id integer, street varchar(50), shape geometry) 
streets (id integer, name varchar(50), shape geometry)
```

Each pipeline passes/intersects several streets.

### Need

I need to:

1. Fill the street field in the pipelines automatically and
2. I need to know to which street does the pipeline "belong the most".

I thought about densifiying the vertices of the each pipeline at a maximum 5 meter distance from each other, and do the analysis on them and then statistically find out the answer.

**How In Postgis can I create a table that presents the geometry for each point of the pipelines along with their corresponding id?**

Answer (score 3):

Your answer did help, although it didn't do what I wanted.

I found out how to do it:

```
select id, (st_dumpPoints(st_segmentize(shape, 5))).geom as geom 
from pipelines;
```

Answer (score 2):

Here should be `SELECT` for it, just convert to `SELECT INTO` if it works

```sql
SELECT 
      id 
      ,(ST_Dump(the_geom)).path as pipe_path  
      ,(ST_Dump(the_geom)).geom as the_geom 
FROM 
      pipelines
```

(I don't have Postgis installation with linestring to test this)